# Laravel sail problem with migrations, the console does not return anything

Tags: php, laravel, docker

I have a problem with laravel sail. My problem is I can't migrate models. I used the command `vendor/bin/sail artisan migrate` but the console gives me nothing, no error, It also did not create any tables in the database. When I went to the project website and tried to create a new user, I could click the migration button and everything worked. `sail node --version` or similar commands also do not return anything

```
    # For more information: https://laravel.com/docs/sail
version: '3'
services:
    web:
        build:
            context: ./vendor/laravel/sail/runtimes/8.0
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
            args:
                WWWGROUP: '${WWWGROUP}'
        image: sail-8.0/app
        ports:
            - '80:80'
        environment:
            WWWUSER: '${WWWUSER}'
            LARAVEL_SAIL: 1
        volumes:
            - '.:/var/www/html'
        networks:
            - sail
        depends_on:
            - mysql
    mysql:
        image: 'mysql:8.0'
        platform: linux/amd64
        container_name: clinic_db
        restart: unless-stopped
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_DB_PORT:-3306}:3306'
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_DATABASE: '${DB_DATABASE}'
            MYSQL_USER: '${DB_USERNAME}'
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 'yes'
        volumes:
            - 'sailmysql:/var/lib/mysql'
        networks:
            - sail
        healthcheck:
          test: ["CMD", "mysqladmin", "ping"]
    phpmyadmin:
      image: 'phpmyadmin:latest'
      ports:
        - 8080:80
      environment:
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
      links:
        - "mysql:db"
      depends_on:
        - mysql
      networks:
        - sail
networks:
    sail:
        driver: bridge
volumes:
    sailmysql:
        driver: local
```

Works on macbook pro m1. Can anyone fix this error?

Comment: would like to try to read my tutorial?
https://dogcomp.medium.com/kickstart-your-laravel-web-app-using-laravel-sail-30276265e588

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this in my project. I had to add this to my .env

```
APP_SERVICE=laravel
```

where "laravel" was the the name of the container for the app. so in your case it would be

```
APP_SERVICE=web
```

My particular project that had the issue was an old laravel 5.7 project that we recently updated to laravel 8.x. I didn't run into this issue on newer installs. Maybe more recent versions of laravel do not need this extra .env variable?